# how to add form models one by one on ajax (add more) in yii1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, yii

I have a form in YII1 and have a model extends CFormModel for this form.
I also having a add more button at the last of the form.  When I click on the button, I want to add same fields of the model to the form . I have done it but my fields validations are not working.

What can I do for validation to work for it???

Comment: its like repeater field ? or a jquery that append new fields ?

Comment: @jay its like repeater fields